# PyQt4 dealing with multiple Qtimers

Tags: timer, pyqt4

My app needs to display 2 timers according the current state . 
i managed to deal with 1 timer without any problem .
here is a snippet from  my code :

```
    self.timer_clock = QtCore.QTimer(self)
    self.timer_clock.timeout.connect(self.Time)
    dis_time = "{0}:{1}".format(m,s)
    self.clockladh450.display(dis_time) 

def Time(self):

    global s,m,h
    if s < 59:
        s += 1
    else:
        if m < 59:
            s = 0
            m += 1
        elif m == 59 and h < 24:
            h += 1
            m = 0
            s = 0
        else:
            self.timer_clock.stop()

    time = "{0}:{1}".format(m,s)

    self.clockladh450.setDigitCount(len(time))
    self.clockladh450.display(time)


def Reset(self):
    global s,m
    s = 0
    m = 0
    time = "{0}:{1}".format(m,s)
    self.clockladh450.setDigitCount(len(time))
    self.clockladh450.display(time)     

def Clock (self,clock_status='',action = '',host = '') : 
    global s,m,h
    if action == 'stop' : 
        self.timer_clock.stop()
        self.clock_dict[str(host)] = 'sleeping'

    if action == 'start' :
        if clock_status == 'sleeping':
            self.Reset()
            self.clock_dict[str(host)] = 'working'
            self.timer_clock.start(1000)
```

This code deals with 1 timer  and updates the lcd perfectly .
My main problem and struggle is to update 2 lcd's simultaneously.

I need an idea or an approach so i can deal with 2,3 or even 4 timers in real time .